# Jasper jrxml files not included in Grails 3 war

Tags: jasper-reports, war, build.gradle, grails-3.0

I am using Jasper Reports in my Grails 3 application to generate PDF files. I had some issue with Jasper Report plugin for Grails. So we are using Jasperreport jars to generate the PDF.

```
compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.2.1'
```

I created a 'JasperReports' in project level and added all the jrxml and jasper files. In the development environment I use the below way to compile the report.

```
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport('JasperReports/FYF_Report.jrxml')
```

Everything works fine in development but when the war is generated it is not including the 'JasperReports' folder. I tried adding the folder in conf but it did not work.

Let me know if I am missing any configuration to include the 'JasperReports' folder in war.

Comment: Do you have a step by step link that explains how to configure grails 3 to use jasper reports?

Comment: I followed this example to generate the pdf files -http://ezsnippet.blogspot.com/2014/07/grails-using-jasper-report-without.html

Comment: For a better performance you can skip compiling the jrxml file everytime and use the .jasper file.

Comment: I see a updated jasper plugin for grails 3. I did not use it but you can try - https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding the JasperReports folder in src/main/webapp. Path to access the files will be different in local and Production, So I am getting the real path from context as below

```
            def sc=session.getServletContext()
            def reportsPath=sc.getRealPath("/")
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportsPath+'JasperReports/FYF_Report.jrxml')
```